# onChange function should not affect other state with same name in json

Tags: reactjs

Currently, I have a problem where one Onchange function is used for the json mapped data, if i change any one state in that, then it is fixed to all other state with same name. how to setstate to 
each state with its appropriate value

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Show us your code, Use spread operator for changing specific part of the state.

Answer (score 1):

Clone your json object using spread operator. Then do modifications in your cloned object. Then setState using the modifed clone object. If you can share the code we can help you better.